# Buildout + Nose failing with passed options options

Tags: python, buildout, nose

After running a buildout operation on my project, I can run `nose` with the following command:

```
# ./bin/nosetests

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.310s
```

However, when I try to pass options (such as `-w` for the base directory, I get the following:

```
# ./bin/nosetests -vv --detailed-errors --exe
Usage: nosetests [options]

nosetests: error: no such option: -v
```

I've checked the test files which are being ran, and removed all lines importing either `getopt` or `OptionParser` to ensure they're not getting in the way, but I'm still getting the same error regardless.

I believe one of the files we're testing requires `getopt` to function... is there any way I can get `nosetests` to work with buildout without these errors?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [noserunner](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pbp.recipe.noserunner/0.2.4) buildout recipe

Here is example buildout.cfg:

```
[buildout]
parts = test
index = http://download.zope.org/simple

[test]
recipe = pbp.recipe.noserunner
eggs = pbp.recipe.noserunner
working-directory = ${buildout:directory}
```

This will create script `test` in bin directory. Runner will run all tests found in path set in `working-directory`